# How to return objects unique based on LocId from all location?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 I face issue : I can't return distinct or unique objects based on LocId .

I need to return object unique from array of object all Locations .

```
allLocations:any[]=[];
ngOnInit()
{

this.locationsService.allLocations.forEach(loc => {
      let d = this.locationsService.allLocations.findIndex(x => x.Locid == loc.Locid);
      if (d !== -1) {
        this.locationsService.allLocations.splice(d, 1);
}
```

and on html component code as below :

```
<tr  *ngFor="let l of locationsService.allLocations">
                <td class="z2-boxstyle1-td-colcontent">
                  <div> {{l.Locid}} </div>
                </td>
</tr>
```

result of array is :

```
[
{"Locid":40903,"GPS1":"42.5913974,-71.3277873","CompanyID":1000339},
{"Locid":40900,"GPS1":"42.588432,-71.31720900000001","CompanyID":1000339}
{"Locid":40900,"GPS1":"42.588432,-71.31720900000001","CompanyID":1000339}
]
```

Because Locid is same on two object so I return distinct and it must be as below :

Expected Result :

```
[
{"Locid":40903,"GPS1":"42.5913974,-71.3277873","CompanyID":1000339},
{"Locid":40900,"GPS1":"42.588432,-71.31720900000001","CompanyID":1000339}
]
```

Comment: thank you for reply but I use on html like this let l of locationsService.allLocations so what i change on html component to accept your code

Comment: if imake it as this.locationsService.allLocations = this.locationsService.allLocations.reduce .... will work or not .

Comment: I need o do as above comment because html will not work if i make var res=this.locationsService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, the order of the element gets changed in the array as soon as you `.splice` it.

Your intention looks like you just don't wanna duplicate the values.

You can do something like this using `.reduce`:

```
var res = this.locationsService.allLocations.reduce((a,v)=>{
  if(!a[v.Locid]){
    a[v.Locid] = v;
  }
return a
},{});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Or you can just take an empty list, keep pushing the values in it from `this.locationsService.allLocations` as long as `Locid` of any of the element in this list is not found there already. **(2-passes)**

Or, you can use `.filter` and `.findIndex` to do the job. **(2-passes)**

However, I would **NOT** recommend these approaches for they will require two passes and `.reduce` with a single pass will perform better.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by Locid

```js
var newArr = arr.filter((x, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.Locid === x.Locid )));

console.log(newArr);
```